# When $e^{w}=e^{z}$ how are complex variables $w$ and $z$ related to each other?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm having a hard time understanding the answer which is:

$$e^{w-z}=1$$
$$\therefore w-z=2\pi ni$$

What I understand is that only when $w-z=0$ the exponential $e^{w-z}$ becomes $1$. However, that would mean that $0=2\pi ni$ which does not make any sense. I'm also wondering what would happen if I chose to use $z-w$ instead of $w-z$ for my answer. Any ideas?

Comment: "*only* when $w-z=0$ the exponential $e^{w-z}$ becomes $1$": no, not *only* then.

Comment: The equation $e^x = 1$ for $x\in \mathbb{C}$ is solved by all $x = 2\pi n \mathrm{i}$ with $n\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @AnneBauval you're right, thanks, I edited it

Comment: The complex exponential is not injective, you cannot conclude $0=2\pi n \mathrm{i}$. And also $\exp(2\pi n \mathrm{i})=1$.

Comment: If I assume that $z=x+iy$ then what happens to the $iy$ part?

Comment: Your question is unclear but may be this answers it: $e^{x+iy}=e^xe^{iy},$ and $e^{iy}=\cos y+i\sin y.$ (This is why $\exp$ is $2\pi\mathrm i$-periodic.)

Comment: I have to translate from Japanese, so my translation might be off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I understand is that only when $w - z = 0$ the exponential $e^{w - z}$ becomes $1$. However, that would mean that $0 = 2 \cdot \pi \cdot n \cdot i$ which does not make any sense.

I think your problem is the inverse of the exponential function with the natural logarithm. You probably learned in school that the logarithm of a number has exactly one result, but in complex numbers the logarithm is multivalued. The solution $\ln\left( 1 \right) = 0$ is only on the main branch of the logarithm.

A simple way to derive the other solutions is based on [Euler's formula](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerFormula.html) $\exp\left( x \cdot i \right) = \cos\left( x \right) + \sin\left( x \right) \cdot i$ and the inverse trigonometric functions:
$$
\begin{align*}
\exp\left( x \cdot i \right) &= \cos\left( x \right) + \sin\left( x \right) \cdot i\\
\underbrace{1}_{\text{real part}} &= \cos\left( x \right) + \sin\left( x \right) \cdot i\\
1 &= \Re\left( \cos\left( x \right) + \sin\left( x \right) \cdot i \right)\\
1 &= \underbrace{\cos\left( x \right)}_{\text{periodic to } 2 \cdot \pi}\\
1 &= \cos\left( x - 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi \right)\\
\arccos\left( 1 \right) &= x - 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi\\
0 &= x - 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi\\
x &= 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi\\
\\
&\Rightarrow \exp\left( 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi \cdot i \right) = \cos\left( 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi \right) + \sin\left( 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi \right) \cdot i = 1 + 0 \cdot i = 1\\
\end{align*}
$$

Another simple derivation is via the complex argument $\arg\left( z \right)$ and [Euler's formula](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerFormula.html) $\exp\left( x \cdot i \right) = \cos\left( x \right) + \sin\left( x \right) \cdot i$:
$$
\begin{align*}
\ln\left( z \right) &= \ln\left( \left| z \right| \cdot e^{\arg\left( z \right) \cdot i} \right)\\
\ln\left( z \right) &= \ln\left( \left| z \right| \right) + \ln\left( e^{\arg\left( z \right) \cdot i} \right)\\
\ln\left( z \right) &= \ln\left( \left| z \right| \right) + \arg\left( z \right) \cdot i\\
\end{align*}
$$
$$
\begin{align*}
\exp \left( \ln\left( z \right) \right) &= \exp\left( \ln\left( \left| z \right| \right) + \arg\left( z \right) \cdot i \right)\\
1 &= \exp\left( \ln\left( \left| 1 \right| \right) + \arg\left( 1 \right) \cdot i \right)\\
1 &= \exp\left( 0 + 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi \cdot i \right)\\
1 &= \exp\left( 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi \cdot i \right)\\
\end{align*}
$$

However, this does not mean that $0 \overset{?}{=} 2 \cdot \pi \cdot n \cdot i$ is the same. They are just solutions to the same equation, but they themselves lie on different branches. It's similar to taking the square root: Solving $x^{2} = 1$ for x, you get $x = 1 \text{ and } x = -1$, but that doesn't mean that they're equal.

> I'm also wondering what would happen if I chose to use $z - w$ instead of $w - z$ for my answer.

It wouldn't change anything. With the change, the relation from before would still remain. The result would just be a different integer, but the two statements are still the same.

$$
\begin{align*}
e^{z} = e^{w} &\wedge e^{z} = e^{w}\\
\frac{e^{z}}{e^{w}} = 1 &\wedge 1 = \frac{e^{w}}{e^{z}}\\
e^{z - w} = 1 &\wedge 1 = e^{w - z}\\
z - w = 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi \cdot i &\wedge 2 \cdot g \cdot \pi \cdot i = w - z\\
z = w + 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi \cdot i &\wedge -w + 2 \cdot g \cdot \pi \cdot i = -z\\
z = w + 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi \cdot i &\wedge w - 2 \cdot g \cdot \pi \cdot i = z\\
z = w + 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi \cdot i &\wedge w + 2 \cdot \underbrace{-g}_{\text{another integer}} \cdot \pi \cdot i = z\\
z = w + 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi \cdot i &\wedge w + 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi \cdot i = z\\
\end{align*}
$$